# React 'load' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying to implement Netlify identity with React [here](https://www.coding-mentors.com), using [this guide](https://github.com/netlify-labs/react-netlify-identity)

But, I get the error `'load' is not defined  no-undef`

It is referring to this line

```
load(loginUser(email, password, true))
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useIdentityContext } from 'react-netlify-identity';
import { navigate } from "@reach/router" // from login tutorial

// log in/sign up example
function Login() {
  const { loginUser, signupUser } = useIdentityContext();
  const formRef = React.useRef();
  const [msg, setMsg] = React.useState('');

  const signup = () => {
    const email = formRef.current.email.value;
    const password = formRef.current.password.value;

    signupUser(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        console.log('Success! Signed up', user);
        navigate('/dashboard');
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err) || setMsg('Error: ' + err.message));
  };

  return (
    <form
      ref={formRef}
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target.email.value;
        const password = e.target.password.value;
        load(loginUser(email, password, true))
          .then(user => {
            console.log('Success! Logged in', user);
            navigate('/dashboard');
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err) || setMsg('Error: ' + err.message));
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <label>
          Email:
          <input type="email" name="email" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Password:
          <input type="password" name="password" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        <button onClick={signup}>Sign Up </button>
        {msg && <pre>{msg}</pre>}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

  export default Login;
```

Comment: And where is `load` defined?  What do you expect that function to do and why?

Comment: hm.. to be fair, I don't exactly know what it should do - probably login user via Netlify identity widget... here is more detailed github source https://github.com/netlify-labs/react-netlify-identity/blob/master/examples/example-reach-router/src/App.tsx

Comment: Looks like your implementation of that example is incomplete.  Note how they define `load` here: `const [isLoading, load] = useLoading();`

Comment: I just added that, also did ``` import useLoading from '../useLoading';``` here is useLoading file https://github.com/netlify-labs/react-netlify-identity/blob/master/examples/example-reach-router/src/useLoading.tsx
Now I get ReferenceError: useLoading is not defined

Comment: Ok, as an alternative solution, I have found another better netlify identity widget https://github.com/netlify-labs/react-netlify-identity-widget